# how to run a NuxtJS project automatically

Tags: vue.js, github, npm, nuxtjs

NuxtJS project management is developed on GitHub.
The following is the development procedure.

1.Push updates from your local PC to the GitHub remote repository.
2.Log in to your hosting server and pull the remote repository to retrieve the differences.
3.Then run npm run build and npm run generate to update the project.

Is there a way to run npm run * automatically after downloading the differences from the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for GitHub webhooks. [See the documentation here.](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)